# Getting an error message when trying to push to an array

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
  if (typeof $scope.grid.data == 'undefined') {
        $scope.grid.data = [];
  }
  $scope.grid.data.push(result);
```

I put in the check for undefined but I am still getting an error message from the push saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of null
```

Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always been fine with a simple :

```
if (!$scope.grid.data) {
    $scope.grid.data = [];
}
```

This should catch it in both situations (null & undefined).

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjbasti/kxGJU/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjbasti/kxGJU/2/

Answer (score 2):

As the error message shows, the object in question is `null`, not `undefined`.  The two are different values, and the way you're checking will only check for undefined.  The best way to check whether an object is `undefined` **or** `null` is to leverage the fact that `null` and `undefined` implicitly convert between each other, and do:

```
if ($scope.grid.data == null) {
```

Comment: A couple examples showing this at  http://jsfiddle.net/5kdG8/ and http://jsfiddle.net/kxGJU/